# set domain name(digitalocean, nginx, django)

Tags: django, nginx

website is up and running, but I connect to it using public IP. On nginx config i put

```
Server {
        PORT 80;
        Server_name MY_PUBLIC_IP;
```

}

I bought a domain on goddady and wanna use it so connect with domain name and not with public IP. How I do that?

**Solved:**
I had to change nameservers from godaddy default to digitalsocean, change server_name to
    Server_name my.domain.ext; 
on django settings.py 
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['my.domain.ext'] and finally network linking on digital ocean

Answer (score 2):

DigitalOcean has great tutorials on how to setup your server. This link is probably what you need:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Follow that tutorial and you should be good to go. There are similar articles for other distributions if you are not using Ubuntu.

Since you are using a real domain (and not example.com), you'll need to add the domain to your DigitalOcean droplet by clicking on the Networking link in the top menu. Here's a direct link to the page, if you are already logged in to your DO account: https://cloud.digitalocean.com/networking/domains

Hope that helps.

Comment: I follow similar guidefor 16.04 and website is up and running, but i can visit it with public  ip. I want to set it using "eviacatalog.net" so when I type this address to web browser open my site, and show this while surfing/using my site. Is only I have to do Networking link? I try it but not work. I do it again...